# Animation.css bug on iOS only

Tags: animation, jquery-animate, animate.css

I am using animations from the [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) library.

Everything looks good until I check the site on my iPhone. It works fine when I use the chrome developer tool device toolbar iPhone setting.

The background while the animation is going on gets distorted, it seems like it is zooming in really far.

I am using the fadeInDown and bounceInUp animations which I read might increase the document height?

Any suggestions or help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I'll post my site just in case https://clipz.netlify.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can set `Overflow: hidden` to Parent container. So that it will not increase the height when animating.
Tested and verified ;)

Thanks